# On-premise TFS dashboard extension not saving cookie

Tags: cookies, tfs

I am setting a cookie on on-premise TFS dashboard from an extension installed on there. We are using TFS 2015 update 3

The code is:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires;
```

The cookie however is not being saved and can't be retrieved later.

The same extension installed on VSTS dashboard in the cloud works fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is en expected behavior for now. Since 3'rd party extensions are sandboxed using the HTML5 iframe sandbox attribute in on-premise TFS to prevent these extensions' scripts (which get served from the same domain as TFS) from having access to client-side variables, data, cookies, etc normally only accessible to the TFS product scripts. The side effect of the sandbox attribute is that extensions on-prem don't have access to cookie storage.

Comment: Does this also happen in later versions of the on-premise TFS dashboard (currently using TFS2015 update 3) ? thanks

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it also applies to TFS2017.

Comment: This sounds really unnecessary. I may be wrong as I just read the sandbox spec, so let me know if that's the case. However I don't see why restricting access to parent domain data should require disabling cookie functionality for extensions.  Even if the sandbox spec has lumped these together, the functionality could seemingly be restored by giving extensions an api that enables cookie functionality for restricted and isolated usage of the extension itself.